# Error E-Mails in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I am running a project in tornado,  I would prefer not to check log files regularly for uncaught errors and have "email someone" or "store in db" (preferred MongoDB).

Tornado doesn't seems to have (at least in the documentation) a method to do this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: not what you are asking for but perhaps useful for your problem; do you know sentry? (getsentry.com)

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli No support for Tornado :-(

Comment: OOPS, sorry it does support Tornado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create as many custom exceptions handlers:

1. The first which stores the serialized exception into Mongo (using Motor)
2. The second, to email the serialized exception, via logging.handlers.SMTPHandler.

Have a look to: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html

How I do, in my Tornado apps:

- Create an ApplicationException class which stores the content of the traceback as a string
- Save the ApplicationException instances generated on runtime by my code on exception into Cassandra or Mongo, using a save method of ApplicationException class
- Send via email, some specific ApplicationException subclass objects using the smtp handler

I usually use this, when implementing tornado based client / server solution, so that I can send the ApplicationException objects as json over https, to my server, which can the decode it and store in DB / email it to the admins.

All this can be quite long to learn and implement, but it worth doing it.

Comment: didn't know that you need Mongo to send an error mail :/

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli for some processing, like the frequency and severity of the error. based on that it'll send email using cron

Comment: @Apero Thanks.  `logging.handlers.SMTPHandler` is it thread safe?

Comment: The best practice is to prefork an thread dedicated to the logging, before starting the IOLoop, and then, each tornado threads / processes, send their logs to this thread, over a basic socket implementation (see tornado.socket, tornado,prefork, ...)